# Associate a UITableViewController to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I am working on an iOS application and i need your help guys !

My home page is a UIView, in this UIView i have a UIImageView,..., and also a UITableView.

I create a UITableViewController class and i need to associate this class to my UITableView.

How can i do ?

Best regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do u want to create a UITableViewController for it. Simply create a UIViewController and append the UITableViewControllerDelegate and UITableViewDataSource to it to take control of your UITableView:

```
 SomeClass : UIViewController <UITableViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewControllerDataSource>
```

in the viewDidLoad you have to assign the delegate/datasource of the tableview to your UIViewController:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self; 
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works... I append UITableViewControllerDelegate and UITableViewDataSource on my RootViewCOntroller (HomeViewController) and in the viewDidLoad method i wrote : 
`self.homeTableView.delegate = self;
    self.homeTableView.dataSource = self;`
homeTableView is my TableView IBOutlet.

Note : if you can edit your answer and replace delegte with delegate  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose your "homepage" is RootViewController Class (.h/.m/.xib), you will extend this class to have UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. In your definition of UITableView you will set the delegate and the datasource to RootViewController and add the required methods for cell rendering.

No UITableViewController required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I create a UITableView (HomeTableView) and i extend this class to have UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource and i added the required methods.
In my HomeViewController and in the viewDidLoad method i did : 
`HomeTableView * tableViewHome = [[HomeTableView alloc]init];
    self.tableView = tableViewHome;`

It didn't work. Maybe i forgot something ?

Comment: I think u are messing up some things. Take a look at the Apple Documentation particularly at the MVC design pattern. You don't need to create a UITableViewController and you can't assign controllers to UI elements

Comment: @MrA59, no you don't create make the UITableView the delegate, you make the UIViewController the delegate of the UITableView.  See MrBr's answer.

Comment: Thanks guys !

I append UITableViewControllerDelegate and UITableViewDataSource on my RootViewCOntroller (HomeViewController) and in the viewDidLoad method i wrote : 
`self.homeTableView.delegate = self;
    self.homeTableView.dataSource = self;`
homeTableView is my TableView IBOutlet.